# How can I change the speed of the "marching ants" in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

When I make a selection in GIMP, I would like to make the selection boundaries more prominent by changing marching ant speed, but I can't find the setting.
Im using GIMP 2.8 on Ubuntu and I have looked through the "preferences" options, but I just cant see it.

Where can I find the control for changing marching ants speed?

Comment: +1 simply for "marching ants" -- I had no idea there was a term for this!

Answer (score 4):

You can set this in the your gimprc file. See http://www.gimp.org/man/gimprc.html

(marching-ants-speed 200)
Speed of marching ants in the selection outline. This value is in milliseconds (less time indicates faster marching). This is an integer value.

Answer (score 2):

I found the control for changing marching ants speed under

<kbd>edit</kbd> > <kbd>preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Image Windows</kbd>

I found this a better option than changing the `gimprc` files directly because

- If you arent used to the `gimprc` syntax you might cause the script to fail on parsing.
- in the GUI control the marching ants speed updates in real time as you adjust the speed dial.
- If you adjust in the GUI, you retain the option of "reseting all tool configs" - in case you broke something and cant remember what changes you  made!
  As the `gimprc` files are hardcoded I suspect they wont reposnd to "reset tool config"